# Return child class from parent's static method

Tags: php, datetime, static-methods

I just learned about this fancy new feature of PHP 5.4.  [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)!  This is perfect for my app.

My app uses DateTime objects, and when I `json_encode` them, I get the following (by running `json_encode([new DateTime])`):

```
[{"date":"2013-09-11 15:39:22","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}]
```

Depending on what `timezone_type` is, the `timezone` value may be different.  I haven't found a good way to parse this object in JavaScript.

So, I decided to create my own DateTime class, and have it serialize to JSON how I wanted.

```
class SerialDateTime extends DateTime implements JsonSerializable{

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return ['timestamp' => $this->getTimestamp()];
    }
}
```

When I now run `json_encode([new SerialDateTime])`, I get this:

```
[{"timestamp":1378914190}]
```

That's much easier to parse in JavaScript.

So, I figured this was a fine solution, but I discovered a problem.  Static methods!  `SerialDateTime::createFromFormat` returns a `DateTime` object!

If I do: `json_encode([SerialDateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '10/31/2011')])`, I get:

```
[{"date":"2011-10-31 15:46:07","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}]
```

Why is this happening?  Why doesn't `SerialDateTime::createFromFormat` return me a `SerialDateTime` object?!

How can I fix this, or do I need to override *all* the static methods from `DateTime` in `SerialDateTime`?  If I do that, how would I even make a new `SerialDateTime` from the `createFromFormat` method?  How can I "cast" a `DateTime` object to `SerialDateTime`?

I thought of a workaround, but there's got to be a better way:

```
public static function createFromFormat($f, $t, $tz=NULL){
    $dateTime = call_user_func(
        array('SerialDateTime', 'parent::createFromFormat'),
        $f, $t, $tz
    );
    $ret = new self();
    return $ret->setTimestamp($dateTime->getTimestamp());
}
```

Could I maybe use `__callStatic` and `return call_user_func_array(array(__CLASS__ , 'parent::'.__FUNCTION__), func_get_args());` or something?

Too bad I can't magically convert `DateTime` to use [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Comment: Isn't it just fine at all, if you override `createFromFormat` method? And why `DateTime` would ever return you something related to child class, when in the principles of OOP, parent classes must not know anything about children. You can always do `new parent()` and never something like `new child()` IMO, overriding methods is fine, it is called polymorphism.

Comment: @Jari: I assumed that `SerialDateTime::createFromFormat` would return me a `SerialDateTime` object without me having to manually override it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - No, thats not the way it works.  All the methods you haven't over written will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you already said & tried, override static method. Method `createFromFormat` by default returns the `DateTime` object, so you only need to fix returning part so it will return your object `SerialDateTime` instead of `DateTime`.

```
class SerialDateTime extends DateTime implements JsonSerializable {

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return ['timestamp' => $this->getTimestamp()];
    }

    public static function createFromFormat($format, $time, $timezone = null)
    {
        if ($timezone) {
            $dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time, $timezone);
        } else {
            $dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time);
        }

        return new self($dt->format(self::W3C));
    }

}

echo json_encode(new SerialDateTime);
echo json_encode(SerialDateTime::createFromFormat('Y', '2013'));
```

It doesn't matter how you call static method `createFromFormat`, it will always return `DateTime` object; so all your ideas of automatically rewriting static methods will fail, **because you need to modify method with new logic (return instance of other object)**, and this cannot be accomplished with auto-call-method-magic-or-something.

Late static bindings would be great if it were implemented in the `DateTime::createFromFormat` method like :

```
public static function createFromFormat($format, $time, $timezone = null)
{
    // logic of converting $time from format $format to some default format 
    return new static($newTime);
}
```

... but it is not ;( [Source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L2652)

Answer (score 1):

So, I will post my answer here.

In my opinion overriding static function `createFromFormat` is the best way to deal with your problem.

Because:

- You code will stay clean (without any unnecessary `call_user_func`)
- It is just right that you override parent class methods and keep the class logics inside class.
- Your class `SerialDateTime` will be futher reusable. (if you want to import only class code)

It is not necessary though to override all methods (unless you implement an interface). Override just only those you need.